# question about coplanar vectors

Tags: vectors

I'm working through a question on vector algebra:

Let ${\bf a}$, ${\bf b}$, and ${\bf c}$ be coplanar vectors related via 
$$
  \alpha{\bf a} + \beta{\bf b} + \gamma{\bf c} = 0
$$
where $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$ are not all zero. Show that the condition for the points with position vectors $u\,{\bf a}$, $v\,{\bf b}$, and $w\,{\bf c}$ to be colinear is 
$$
  \frac{\alpha}{u} + \frac{\beta}{v} + \frac{\gamma}{w} = 0 
$$

I thought that for colinearity we needed 
$$
   u\,{\bf a} \times v\,{\bf b} = u\,{\bf a} \times w\,{\bf c} = v\,{\bf v} \times w\,{\bf c} = 0\
$$

which would give

$$
\begin{vmatrix}
i\ & j\ & k\, \\
u\,{\bf a}i\ & u\,{\bf a}j\ & u\,{\bf a}k\ \\
v\,{\bf b}i\ & v\,{\bf b}j\ & v\,{\bf b}k\
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
i\ & j\ & k\, \\
u\,{\bf a}i\ & u\,{\bf a}j\ & u\,{\bf a}k\ \\
w\,{\bf c}i\ & w\,{\bf c}j\ & w\,{\bf c}k\
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
i\ & j\ & k\, \\
v\,{\bf b}i\ & v\,{\bf b}j\ & v\,{\bf b}k\ \\
w\,{\bf c}i\ & w\,{\bf c}j\ & w\,{\bf c}k\
\end{vmatrix}
=
0
$$
expanding this we get

$$
u\,{\bf a}j\,v\,{\bf b}k\ = u\,{\bf a}k\,v\,{\bf b}j\ \\
u\,{\bf a}k\,v\,{\bf b}i\ = u\,{\bf a}i\,v\,{\bf b}k\ \\
u\,{\bf a}i\,v\,{\bf b}j\ = u\,{\bf a}j\,v\,{\bf b}i\
$$

dividing by $ u\,v\ $ gives

$$
{\bf a}j\,{\bf b}k\ = {\bf a}k\,{\bf b}j\ \\
{\bf a}k\,{\bf b}i\ = {\bf a}i\,{\bf b}k\ \\
{\bf a}i\,{\bf b}j\ = {\bf a}j\,{\bf b}i\
$$

but then it seems to me that the constants $ u\ $, $ v\ $ & $ w\ $ are redundant, since they cancel out... I'm clearly missing something, can someone help?